# Is there a way to style the contents of a iframe using CSS?

Tags: html, css, iframe

```
<iframe src="#link">
#document
<!doctype html>
  <html>
     ...
  </html>
</iframe>
```

How would I apply my own CSS styling to any the elements inside the `#document`
Can I do this only using CSS, not using Jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: Without javascript/jquery I believe this is impossible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do what you're looking for with CSS only. You can style elements inside an iframe using JavaScript *but* as long as the iframe is on the same domain as your site. I must add that doing this with JS is a real pain in the butt though.

If the iframe comes from a different domain, all bets are off. This is done in order to protect sites from being hijacked (imagine I make a site with a full-screen iframe of Youtube and then lure people into giving me their password, sort of thing).

Comment: *If the iframe comes from a different domain, all bets are off* - not 100% true, as [CORS can be implemented for trusted system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: True! I made the assumption that you wouldn't have control of the other domain. But if you do, you're better off changing css on that side rather than messing with CORS

Answer (score 0):

Both documents exist in the equivalent of two different browser tabs. CSS alone cannot style the contents of an iframe, but can of course style the iframe itself. Even using JavaScript (jQuery) won't work all the time.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.